# Using GAPI script how to get refresh token on google sign in

Tags: reactjs, google-signin, react-google-login

I have integreated google sign in with my react application using gapi script and react-google-login package.

Sign in feature is working as expected but along with access token I need refresh token as well to get the new access token whenever it expired.

Can anyone please help on how to retrieve refresh token on google signin ?

Note : I am not calling any google account API only integrated package and GAPI script